# Sci-fi book identification-Feral Child to Superhuman

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a sci-fi/thriller novel many years ago, probably published between 1980-1990 in the USA in English that had the following elements:

1. A feral child/teen is found in the wilderness, but his brain is underdeveloped.
2. Scientists "fix" him with a brain tissue transplant to increase his intelligence.
3. The child rapidly develops vast intelligence, surpassing his doctors.
4. The doctors hire a prostitute to do an experiment on the teen/experiment
5. Teen develops telepathy
6. Teen uses super brain to augment another low-intelligence female patient.
7. The book ends with the end of the world and the teen and his newly-enhanced female friend watch the end of the world from a jungle. There is a definite Adam/Eve vibe to the ending.
8. Protagonist may be named Adam.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After much research on multiple search engines, I found the answer!

"The Adam Project" by William Woolfolk.

[image: The Adam Project by William Woolfolk]

Though published, Amazon does not even list the book at all. I eventually found a single reference to it on a British fiction site.

http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/books/n/n17970.htm

Apparently the author had better success with comic books than novels and so published relatively few. That said, Wikipedia says he sold a great deal of them.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Woolfolk

Comment: It sounds awful. That said, congrats on finding it.

Comment: Thank you. What bothers me the most was it was not a great novel, but the lack of a title was driving me crazy.